# What is the simplest way to secure my lambda's functionURL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, authorization

I have a lambda that needs to be accessed by a user. They must be able to visit the URL in a browser. What is the simplest way to secure the functionURL so that if the URL were to leak, there would be another layer of security that would need to be gone through?

I can't use AWS_IAM as the requirement is that the user clicks on the link and I can't expect them to deal with AWS SigV4.

A simple solution would be using the queryparams and adding an access code parameter that is checked for when the lambda is called but this seems like a bad idea for various reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda function URLs only support `AWS_IAM` and `NONE` for the `AuthType` parameter, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html).

> I can't use AWS_IAM as the requirement is that the user clicks on the link and I can't expect them to deal with AWS SigV4.

Then you need to use an AWS API Gateway, and place your lambda function behind it.